# Invertir el orden al mostrar objetos extraídos desde firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic2

Tengo un listado de objetos extraídos desde firebase y necesito esos mismos datos pero invertir el orden en que se muestran:

```
//QUERY QUE EXTRAES LOS DATOS DESDE FIREBASE CON ANGULARFIRE2
this.ben = this.database.list('/Bencina', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'precioBencina'
  }
});

//RECORRO LA PROMISE Y ALMACENOS LOS DATOS EN B
this.ben.forEach(element =>{
  this.b = [];
  element.forEach(ele =>{
    if(ele.idCiudad == this.idCiudadGlobal){
      //aqui donde se guardan los datos necesitos invertir el orden
      console.log(this.b.push(ele));
    }
  })
})

// ACA MUESTRO LOS DATOS Y NECESITOS QUE SE MUETREN EN OTRO ORDEN
<ion-item *ngFor="let data of b">
  <ion-avatar item-left>
    ${{data .precioBencina}}
  </ion-avatar>
  <h2>{{data .nombreBencinera}}</h2>
  <h3>{{data .calleBencinera}}</h3>
  <p>{{data .fechaPublicacion}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza `Array.reverse` que invierte el orden del array:

```js
var numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(numeros);
numeros.reverse();
console.log(numeros);
```

Por lo que en tu caso seria:

```
this.b = [];
  element.forEach(ele =>{
    if(ele.idCiudad == this.idCiudadGlobal){
      //aqui donde se guardan los datos necesitos invertir el orden
      console.log(this.b.push(ele));
    }
  })

// invirtiendo los indices del array
this.b.reverse();
```

Comment: no funciona del todo bien, gracias por la ayuda Einer

Comment: Y puedes decir que exactamente te falla?

Comment: que los ordena en base a un index y eso no es lo que necesito, ya que es una array de objetos lo que necesito ordenar en base al precio de una bencina,

Comment: [ {
  "calleBencinera" : "Picarte 123",
  "fechaPublicacion" : "17-05-2017",
  "idCiudad" : "1",
  "idProvincia" : "1",
  "idRegion" : "1",
  "idTipoBencina" : "2",
  "idbencinera" : "6",
  "nombreBencinera" : "Copec",
  "nombreCiudad" : "Valdivia",
  "nombreProvincia" : "Valdivia",
  "nombreRegion" : "XIV Región de los Ríos",
  "nombreTipoBencina" : "Gasolina Super 95",
  "precioBencina" : "300"
}

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenia el.mismo problema. Hay dos soluciones. Generar un id con numeros negativos y darle el ordenby por el id del post en negativo o crear un recyclerview y en el linearmanager darle inverse.

Comment: Se agradece tu contribución Matias!, pero debes aportar más información para que la respuesta sea de utilidad a otros usuarios,  "generar un id con numeros negativos", como realizar esto, agrega un ejemplo o pequeno script, "linearmanager, a que te refieres con este manager?, este en realidad no existe, te sugiero aportes más información, revisa [answer], saludos!