# Cómo puedo revertir el orden de una lista que genero en base a números que obtengo desde Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Tengo una lista de números en Firebase que va desde 1 hasta X número, ya que va aumentando cada cierto tiempo... La lista se genera sin problemas, pero se genera hacia abajo, es decir, de esta manera:

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
```

Lo que necesito es que se genere de esta manera:

```
...
5
4
3
2
1
```

He intentado agregando reverse por todos lados pero no me ha funcionado...

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
var content = '';  
          firebase.database().ref().child("Users").on('value', function(snapshot){
          if(snapshot.exists()){
            //console.log(snapshot.key)
            content ='<ul>';  
            snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                var val = data.val();

                content += '<li>' + val.Usuario + '</li>';

            });
            content +='</ul>';

            $("#A_Usuarios")append(content);
            }
            });
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias!

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Invertir el orden al mostrar objetos extraídos desde firebase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105028/invertir-el-orden-al-mostrar-objetos-extra%c3%addos-desde-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con el metodo`sort`para ordenar arrays. En tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
var content = '';  
          firebase.database().ref().child("Users").on('value', function(snapshot){
          if(snapshot.exists()){
            snapshot.sort( ( a, b )=>{ return b - a; } );
            //console.log(snapshot.key)
            content ='<ul>';  
            snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                var val = data.val();

                content += '<li>' + val.Usuario + '</li>';

            });
            content +='</ul>';

            $("#A_Usuarios")append(content);
            }
            });
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos

Comment: Hola amigo, sort no es una función de snapshot. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Convierte el resultado de snapshot en un array y haz el foreach sobre el nuevo array ordenado

Answer (score 0):

Usa `Array.prototype.reverse()`

```js
var lista = [1,2,3,4];
var atsil = lista.reverse();
console.info(atsil)
```

`reverse` invierte el orden de los miembros de un objeto de tipo Array independientemente de sus valores

Comment: Tienes razón, pero mi problema es que al parecer no sé cómo aplicarlo en mi código, porque no me ha funcionado y he probado de hartas maneras :/

Comment: @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas Edita tu pregunta para mostrar cómo lo has probado